# How to convert .py file into apk file

Tags: python

I have write a code of a voice assistant for my college minor project in python. But when I'm trying to convert it into apk using kivymd its show error (ImportError: cannot import name 'MDlabel' from 'kivymd.uix.label'). How to fix this error?

source code:
[Voice assistant using python](https://docs.google.com/document/d/115MgZehE0K8qZ02aae8zb5DjjPUTyi7eWLINvQJbZ3Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The conflicting installation setup of the Kivy results in this type of error. Uninstall everything, try making a clean pip install of kivy if you have multiple installed versions or manually installed used kitchen sink from master branch.

Check below link:
https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD/-/issues/118